# MySQL syntax error for server version

Tags: mysql

What the problem with below code, it reverts with an error message "The reported error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`user` bigint(20) NOT NULL, type enum('e','c') NOT NULL, `eidcid` bigint(20) N' at line 1"

Can someone please help???

```
$sqla[] = "CREATE TABLE `" . $GLOBALS['TBL_PREFIX'] . "accesscache` (`cacheid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  type enum('e','c') NOT NULL,  `eidcid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  `result` enum('nok','readonly','ok') NOT NULL,  `timestamp_last_change` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY `cacheid` (`cacheid`), KEY `user` (`user`),  KEY `type` (`type`),  KEY `eidcid` (`eidcid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Interleave Access cache table';";
```

Comment: Add a `,` between `AUTO_INCREMENT`  and `user`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
$sqla[] = "CREATE TABLE `" . $GLOBALS['TBL_PREFIX'] . "accesscache` (`cacheid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  type enum('e','c') NOT NULL,  `eidcid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  `result` enum('nok','readonly','ok') NOT NULL,  `timestamp_last_change` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY `cacheid` (`cacheid`), KEY `user` (`user`),  KEY `type` (`type`),  KEY `eidcid` (`eidcid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Interleave Access cache table';";
```

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 errors, I will show on worked script -

```
CREATE TABLE `accesscache` (
  `cacheid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- need ',' after cacheid
  `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  type enum ('e', 'c') NOT NULL,
  `eidcid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `result` enum ('nok', 'readonly', 'ok') NOT NULL,
  `timestamp_last_change` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cacheid`), -- PK always named as PRIMARY
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `eidcid` (`eidcid`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
DEFAULT charset = utf8
COMMENT = 'Interleave Access cache table'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query. You Forgot to put `,`  after `AUTOINCREMENT`

```
   $sqla[] = "CREATE TABLE `" . $GLOBALS['TBL_PREFIX'] . "accesscache` (`cacheid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  type enum('e','c') NOT NULL,  `eidcid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  `result` enum('nok','readonly','ok') NOT NULL,  `timestamp_last_change` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY `cacheid` (`cacheid`), KEY `user` (`user`),  KEY `type` (`type`),  KEY `eidcid` (`eidcid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Interleave Access cache table';";
```